# My car's revs keep dropping

Tags: engine, lancer, rev-limiter

Please help, should i get a tune-up. I will post a video, so y'all can get a better idea of the issue in the car. 
Please visit link to get an idea of the issue.

https://youtu.be/rKRAHqXe3Pw

Comment: Pull the intake tube off the throttle body and take a look at the plate. Is it dirty? Has the battery gone dead recently? I doubt a tune up will fix your low idle and rev hunting issues.

Comment: Thanks man, ill attempt to do that. i have very basic mechanic skills but i have a very low budget so i don't have time/ resources to do much then to take it in.

Comment: Is the CE light on?

Comment: Also check the engine bay for vacum tubes, check to see if everything is connected

Comment: It appears to be trying to keep the beat. (-: On a serious note, many things can cause engine surge. This article, [**The dreaded engine surge**](http://www.autoserviceprofessional.com/article/92420/The-dreaded-engine-surge), has some helpful tips on what to check. Other than that, due to lack of details, this is too broad of a question.